Clarification on Logic
I want to clarify a few things about logics I hoped you could help me with. As I understand it,
A logic is a logical formal system:

The term "logic" can also be used in a slightly different sense as a countable noun. In this sense, a logic is a logical formal system. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic

A formal system contains both a formal language and rules of inference https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_system
However, a logic also contains both syntax and semantics https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/89770/what-exactly-is-a-logic
A formal language contains an alphabet and a formal grammar
Here's a diagram:
Logic (Logical formal system)
    Formal language/Syntax (Set of well-formed formulas)
        Alphabet
        Formal grammar
    Rules of inference/Semantics (Assignment of truth values)

I wanted to ask:

Am I right in assuming that formal language = syntax and rules of inference = semantics from the above pair of divisions concerning the composition of a logic? I assumed rules of inference like modus ponens were concerned with true statements coming from true statements so it seemed to belong to semantics, though I could also envision using modus ponens as formulaic manipulation with no regard to the truth values.

The top two answers on https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/89770/what-exactly-is-a-logic seem to alternatingly classify proof theory as both semantics and syntax. Which one is it?

Do mathematical theories (say set theory) form separate logics (they contain a slightly different set of symbols) or are they all just a set of wff's in one logic (notably first-order logic)?



See also What is mathematical logic? and In Mathematical Logic, What is a Language? and What is a formal definition of "predicate logic"? and What exactly is a first-order logic?

I would actually make a few more distinctions.
Yes, you can have multiple logics, and there is in fact a whole taxonomy of those. You have classical logic and non-classical logic. Propositional logic and predicate logic. Various kinds of modal logic. Etc. etc.
But these are distinct logics just in what they are about, so this is before we introduce any kind of formal language. Indeed, the same logic can be described by many different formal languages. So, the formal language is not an inherent part of these different logics. If you do include a formal language, and with an accompanying formal semantics, I would say you are talking about a logic system, not just a logic.
And rules of inference are something different yet!  You can have different sets of rules of inference for the same logic system. So again, I would not see rules of inference as an inherent part of a logic .. or even of a logic system. Rather, when you point to different sets of rules of inference, you are talking about different proof systems.
